# How to Print["x=",x] with Style?

Tags: output-formatting, style

How to Print a text and a value with the same Style?, for example `{Bold, Blue, 22}`

```
a=4
Style["The number is ", a  , Blue, 22]
```

The output is text without the variable. With

```
a=4
Style["The number is " -> a  , Blue, 22]
```

obtain `The number is -> 4`.

What  I would like to obtain is the same as with a Print but in blue and larger, and without enormous complications and functions.

With `Manipulate` I reach that with `Dynamic[]` for the variable.

Thank you.

Comment: `Style["The number is " <> ToString@a, Blue, 22]`?.

Comment: Or `Style[Row[{"The Number is ", a}], Blue, 22]`

Comment: `a = 4; 

Style[StringForm["The number is ``", a], Blue, 22]`

Comment: `a = 4; Row[Style[#, Blue, 22] & /@ {"The number is ", a}]`

Comment: What restrictions are you trying to impose with the reference to `Print`?  If you just want a string displayed with style in a notebook,  you can use `Style` with a `StringTemplate`.

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp = StringTemplate["The number is ``"];
Manipulate[Style[tmp@a, Blue, 22], {{a, 4}, 1, 10, 1}]
```